# How to assign a local variable value to state with setState()?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set a value that is local to a function to a state variable. The code looks something like this:

```
function someName(){
  let aVariable = "Value";

  // copy value of aVariable to a state variable
  this.setState(st => {
      guessedWord: aVariable;
  });
}
```

In my problem, aVariable is the result of a few if/else conditionals on a string whose characters are obtained from a set().

I have tried:

```
this.setState({ guessedWord: aVariable });
```

and

```
this.setState({ guessedWord: this.aVariable });
```

and

```
this.setState(() => {
  return {
    guessedWord: finalString
  };
});
```

I am not sure if we cannot assign some variable like this or if I am missing something.

It'd be very helpful if you can help me out here or piont me to some doc which elaborates on this case. Thank you and cheers :-)

Comment: The syntax is correct. What exactly is not working?

Comment: The value of 'guessedWord' does not get updated. I've confirmed that 'aVariable' gets updated through console logs but 'guessedWord' does not reflect the changes.

Comment: This is a hangman game. if you'd like to have a look at the code, its at - 
Repo: https://github.com/coderapex/ReactNoob
File: src/Hangman.js Line 42

Comment: Where do you access the state variable?

Comment: Sorry. It's in folder '10-hangman/src/hangman.js'. https://github.com/coderapex/ReactNoob/blob/master/10-hangman/src/Hangman.js